# What's the default social media app in 14.10?

Tags: 14.10, gwibber, friends-app

Just come back to Ubuntu after an 18 month gap (Forced back onto Windows by employer for a while!) Noticed gwibber is no longer available and new Friends app does not work i.e. No status feed updates for Facebook or Twitter!

What are people using instead?